# Get clicked *ngFor item in router outlet Angular2

Tags: json, angular, routes, router-outlet

I've got an `*ngFor` generated list where each item is rendered from `json`.

What I want is to get the clicked item in my `router-outlet` view while hiding the other items.

Think of it as of a product list and product card. When you click on particular item, you redirected to a full page of that item product. So, I need the same approach.

Now on click I am getting the needed URL. So I don't need to set a special URL for `router-outlet` view, just render the clicked item there.

My `*ngFor` structure:

```
<div class="releases-component">
    <div class="release" 
    *ngFor="let release of releases"
    (click)="routerDisplay($event)">

        <img src="{{release.image}}" 
        alt="Release image" 
        [routerLink]="['/releases', release.id ]">

        <h3 class="release--name" 
        [routerLink]="['/releases', release.id ]">{{release.name}}</h3>

        <span class="release--year" 
        [routerLink]="['/releases', release.id ]">{{release.year}}</span>
    </div>

    <div class="release--view">
        <router-outlet>{{ The Clicked Item! }}</router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

My service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ReleasesService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {

    }


    getReleases() {
        return this.http.request('./allReleases.json')
        .map(res => res.json());
    }

    getData(res: Response){

    }

    getReleaseInfo(){

    }
}
```

My `json`:

```
[
    {
      "id":"release-1",
      "name": "Release1 name",
      "image": "./cover1.jpg",
      "year": "2014"
    },
    {
      "id":"release-2",
      "name": "Release2 name",
      "image": "./release2.jpg",
      "year": "2015"
    }
]
```

And my routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'releases', component: ReleasesComponent },
  { path: 'releases/:id', component: ReleasesComponent },
  { path: 'distro', component: DistroComponent },
  { path: 'contacts', component: ContactsComponent }
];
```

Comment: It's entirely unclear to me what " get the clicked item in my router-outlet view while hiding the other items." could mean. You can't show something in a `<router-outlet>` you tell the router to navigate to a route, and the router shows the component configured for that route in the `<router-outlet>`

Comment: I don't have a component to be shown, just a json based render of html tags.
By the phrase I meant following: I've got a list of items, when I click on an item I am getting redirected to that item's page. But since there's a router outlet I'd like it to show the clicked item only, and that would imitate redirection behavior. But actually it should remove from the view the other items and left only the clicked one with needed json parameters such as name, id, image and year of release in my case.
P.S. Just like in an online store - you see a list of goods, you click and redirected to its page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        <div class="releases-component">
            <div class="release" 
            *ngFor="let release of releases"
            (click)="routerDisplay($event),onSelect(release)">

                <img src="{{release.image}}" 
                alt="Release image" 
                [routerLink]="['/releases', release.id ]">

                <h3 class="release--name" 
                [routerLink]="['/releases', release.id ]">{{release.name}}</h3>

                <span class="release--year" 
                [routerLink]="['/releases', release.id ]">{{release.year}}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="release--view" *ngIf="selectedRelease">
             <label>id: {{selectedRelease.id}}</label><br/>
             <label>name: {{selectedRelease.id}}</label><br/>
             <label>year : {{selectedRelease.year}}</label><br/>
            </div>
        </div>

In you controller:
onSelect(release){
this.selectedRelease=release;
    }
```

Comment: It seems like compiler doesn't support multiple click actions. It throws an error on "routerDisplay($event),onSelect(release)", but if only onSelect is left everything runs well!

Comment: you can use it like: 
"onSelect(($event,release)" in view, 

onSelect(event,release){
this.selectedRelease=release;
this.routerDisplay(event);
    }